# Sort Pivot table based on subtotal

Tags: excel, vba

When I search for `PivotField.AutoSort` method: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.pivotfield.autosort, there is a Parameter called *CustomSubtotal*.

Anyone have the sample, what should I put in for this parameter?

Here the sample table
[sample table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KH0d6.png)

The main objective is use vba to autosort PivotTable based on "C Total".

From
[PivotTable before sort](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCMQj.png) to
[PivotTable after sort](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVv8h.png)

The normal sort based on Grand Total is working.

```
Dim pvt As PivotTable
Set pvt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1)

With pvt
 .PivotFields("Field 1").AutoSort Order:=Excel.XlSortOrder.xlDescending, Field:="Sum of Field 4"
End With
```

When adding in parameter *CustomSubtotal*, cannot work. I had tried both code below:

```
 .PivotFields("Field 1").AutoSort Order:=Excel.XlSortOrder.xlDescending, Field:="Sum of Field 4", CustomSubtotal:="C Total"

 .PivotFields("Field 1").AutoSort Order:=Excel.XlSortOrder.xlDescending, Field:="Sum of Field 4", CustomSubtotal:="C"

 .PivotFields("Field 1").AutoSort Order:=Excel.XlSortOrder.xlDescending, Field:="Sum of Field 4", CustomSubtotal:=1
```

Thanks.

Edited:

By the way, I had a not effective way to achieve the purpose.
By using For Loop, loop through every row of PivotTable, then using `GetPivotData.Value` to compare the value, then exchange their `Position` if needed.

Somehow this method is wasting much time, as I had a long row of data to sort...

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the solution myself...

```
Dim pvt As PivotTable
Set pvt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1)
With pvt
 .PivotFields("Field 1").AutoSort Order:=Excel.XlSortOrder.xlDescending, Field:="Sum of Field 4", PivotLine:=ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotColumnAxis.PivotLines(3), CustomSubtotal:=1
End With
```